# Connecting to an AWS RDS behind a NAT with an SSH tunnel

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, nat, ssh-tunnel

I've set up a MYSQL RDS on AWS, in a private VPC behind a NAT.

With Workbench, I can connect successfully from a remote client into the RDS no problems - so all of the RDS, the NAT and the security groups, etc are all set up correctly.

I've tried a variety of SSH tunnelling examples that I've found, to connect without using Workbench - but nothing is working.

So given that I ssh into the NAT with ssh -i nat.pem ec2-user@nat.ip and the RDS is behind that at rds.endpoint.aws.com - how do I set up an SSH tunnel so that I can just mysql -h into the RDS endpoint through the NAT?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure I tried this earlier, but I must've typo'ed something, as it's now working.

Posting the answer just in case anyone else gets confused by this.

Set up an ssh tunnel on the remote client with:

```
ssh -i nat.pem -f -N -L 3305:rds.endpoint.aws.com:3306 ec2-user@nat.ip
```

then just

`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3305 -u user -p`

Comment: Going to make the assumption that when you refer to your NAT, you mean a NAT instance with a publicly accessible IP address, not a NAT gateway. Just to help others that confuse the two, as I did when I first started working with AWS VPCs.